# Spring Batch Create SubJob

Tags: spring-batch

I have a working spring job that contains multiple steps.  However when I launch this job I want to actually launch a dynamic number of them with a different parameter.  I can do that but these N jobs are really tied together and I want to know when they all complete.

Is there any way for a job to launch sub jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way for a job to launch sub jobs?

You can create a job with one or more steps of type [JobStep](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html) to delegate step processing to (sub) jobs.

Comment: is there a way to set different job parameters for these job steps? It looks like from the logs step job are very similar.  
Job: [SimpleJob: [name=2019-11-13]] launched with the following parameters...

Comment: Yes, parameters can be passed to the sub job via the step execution. From the javadoc of JobStep: `The job is executed with parameters that can be extracted from the step execution`. By default, it will copy the parameters from the parent job, but you can use a custom `JobParametersExtractor` to set different parameters: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html#setJobParametersExtractor-org.springframework.batch.core.step.job.JobParametersExtractor-